# python Streamlit feature for interacting with displayed images

Tags: image, click, display, streamlit, mousemove

IS there a way to interact with streamlit objects such as a image displayed using st.image, a simple interaction like mouse move or mouse click?

Went through streamlit api was not able to find any clue on it.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/custom-component-to-display-clickable-images/21604

Comment: Or maybe something like this ? https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/new-component-html-content-with-click-detection/23370

Answer (score 1):

As per the **Streamlit site**:

You could use: [HTML content with click detection](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/new-component-html-content-with-click-detection/23370)

### Installation

```
pip install st-click-detector
```

### Usage

```
import streamlit as st
from st_click_detector import click_detector

content = """<p><a href='#' id='Link 1'>First link</a></p>
    <p><a href='#' id='Link 2'>Second link</a></p>
    <a href='#' id='Image 1'><img width='20%' src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565130838609-c3a86655db61?w=200'></a>
    <a href='#' id='Image 2'><img width='20%' src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565372195458-9de0b320ef04?w=200'></a>
    """
clicked = click_detector(content)

st.markdown(f"**{clicked} clicked**" if clicked != "" else "**No click**")
```

#### Note:

The click event returns the `id` of the component in question